# Use of Google Cloud Platform with multizone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I need to use a service of compute engine API, however, need to specify the region and zone. How should I set multi zone value to 'zone' parameter of service?

https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/-project-/zones/-zone-/instanceGroupManagers/instanceGroupManager

My instance group is multi zone type, running at europe-west1-b, europe-west1-d, and europe-west1-c, but I can't use a value like europe-west1 to the zone parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of Instance Group Managers (IGMs), which are almost identical.

- Zonal, and
- Regional.

There are two differences between them:

- Service used to managed them (compute.instanceGroupManagers for zonal and compute.regionInstanceGroupManagers for regional),
- Fields you can set (you must set zone for regional but can not set it for regional, reverse that for with region field).

You want to create a regional IGM. So you must send call to compute.regionInstanceGroupManagers.create method **not** set any value to zone field but set value of region field.

If you are just starting it's probably easiest to use [web UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/compute/instances). You can also use command `gcloud compute instance-groups managed create` (with `--region` flag) if you like console. If you want to interact with API more directly [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/compute/v1/compute.regionInstanceGroupManagers.insert) makes that easier.